# Spring Boot, Thymeleaf, Error during execution of processor

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have this thymeleaf template and I cannot find a way to make it work. The thymeleaf template is coded to do a post form like this:

```html
  <form class="mx-auto" method="post" th:object="${provideForm}">
                <div class="mb-3">
                  <label class="form-label">Paciente</label>
                  <select class="form-select" th:field="*{pet}" >
                        <option selected>Seleccione su Mascota</option>
                        <option th:each="i : ${p}" th:value="${i.index}" th:utext="${i}"></option>
                  </select>
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                  <label class="form-label">Servicio</label>
                  <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" th:field="*{service}" >
                    <option selected>Seleccione el Servicio</option>
                    <option th:each="i : ${s}" th:value="${i.index}" th:utext="${i}"></option>
                  </select>
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                  <label class="form-label">Lugar</label>
                  <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example"  th:field="*{veterinary}">
                    <option selected>Seleccione la Veterinaria</option>
                    <option th:each="i : ${v}" th:value="${i.index}" th:utext="${i}"></option>
                  </select>
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                  <label class="form-label">Fecha</label>
                  <input type="date" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" th:field="*{date}">
                 </div> 
                <div class="mb-3">
                  <label class="form-label">Hora</label>
                  <select class="form-select" th:field="*{time}">
                    <option th:each="i : ${#numbers.sequence(0,6)}" th:value="${i}" th:text="'1' + ${i} + ':00:00'"></option>
                   </select>
                 </div> 
               
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Cancelar</button>
              </form>
```

The spring boot is trying to pass the arrays like this:

```java
 @GetMapping(value="/appointmentsView")
    public ModelAndView appointmentsView(){
        if(!Objects.nonNull(authUser)){
            return login();
        }
        updateInfo();
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("appoitnmentsView");

        List<String> displayPets = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(Pet p : pets){
            displayPets.add(p.getName());
        }
        mv.addObject("p", displayPets);

        List<String> displayServices = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(Services s : services){
            displayServices.add(s.getService_name());
        }
        mv.addObject("s", displayServices);

        List<String> displayVeterinaries = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(Veterinary v : veterinaries){
            displayVeterinaries.add(v.getVeterinary_name());
        }
        mv.addObject("v", displayVeterinaries);
        return mv;
    }
```

I am always getting a 500 error code:

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringSelectFieldTagProcessor' (template: "appointmentsView" - line 38, col 47)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:117) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
```

The only way I could fix this problem is by moving the `th:field` that are on the select tags to the option tags. However, by doing that it always return null on the `th:field`

Comment: You can [edit] your question to show the complete stack trace, which may give more specific "caused by..." reasons.

Comment: You can also clarify exactly which line is "line 38", since we don't have line numbers for your `agregarCitaView` template.